# How to set up Wordpress and Flask on the same server with Apache?

Tags: apache-2.4, wordpress, flask

I installed WordPress on my server and it's working fine. Now I'm trying to set up another application made using Flask on the same server. This is what my `.conf` file looks now:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/mydomain.com/public_html>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80 *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomain.com/public_html

    WSGIDaemonProcess test user=www-data group=group-wp threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias /newsletter /var/www/newsletter.wsgi

    <Directory /var/www/html/mydomain.com/public_html/newsletter>
        WSGIProcessGroup test
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/www/html/mydomain.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/mydomain.com/logs/access.log combined

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.mydomain.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mydomain.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

My Flask app `test.py` looks like this

```
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask, g, jsonify, abort, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return "testing"

@app.route('/api/list', methods=['GET'])
def list_all():
    return "also testing"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

and my `newsletter.wsgi` file looks like this:

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/newsletter')

from test import app as application
```

I've installed `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` to run the wsgi script but I'm getting a 404 page at `mydomain.com/newsletter`, `mydomain.com/api_list`, `mydomain.com/newsletter/api_list` and all the other combinations I've tried. Should I be changing `.htaccess`? Should my Flask app be located in the same directory as WordPress? I've already tried moving the app directory to `public_html` and adding the rule `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/newsletter`
 to the `.htaccess` file but it just shows the `.py` and `.wsgi` files, not running the script.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved it:

- I was changing the non-SSL `.conf` file. `certbot` (from Let's Encrypt) automatically creates a new `.conf` with the new SSL settings
- mod_wsgi was using Python 2, for which Flask was not installed
- I uninstalled mod_wsgi, updated Apache with `apt-get` and reinstalled mod-wsgi with `pip3 install mod_wsgi`. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30682386/2393963)
- I checked error.log to sort out the remaining errors